# Hide a region with empty view in it

Tags: views, 8, blocks, theming

I have a region `page_intro` where I display a view, with some CSS on it. When the view is empty (return no result), the region is still displayed (All html code before and after `{{ page.page_intro }}`). Is there a way to compltetly remove it when the view is empty ?

template :

```
{% if page.page_intro %}
    {# #page-intro #}
    <div id="page-intro" class="clearfix">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                {# #page-intro-inside #}
                <div id="page-intro-inside" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 clearfix">
                    {{ page.page_intro }}
                </div>
                {# EOF: #page-intro-inside #}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {# EOF: #page-intro #}
{% endif %}
```

I'm on Drupal 8.2.0 version.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the views template for your view (views-view--page-intro.html.twig, and put the wrapping markup in there, rather than in the page template.

```
{% if rows %}
    <div id="page-intro" class="clearfix">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="page-intro-inside" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 clearfix">
                    {{ rows }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
```

turn on twig debugging to see the template suggestions in your page markup.  this will be the default.services.yml file in your config directory where you have settings.php

```
 twig.config:
    debug: true
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this. Example below is used for node templates:

```
use \Drupal\views\Views;

function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // make the result count available as a variable for a certain content type
  if($node->getType() == 'news') {
    $view = Views::getView('related_news');
    $view->setDisplay('default');
    // contextual relationship filter
    $view->setArguments([$variables['node']->id()]);
    $view->execute();
    $variables['related_news_count'] = count($view->result);
    $variables['related_news'] = $view->render();
  }
}
```

Then, in your node

```
{% if related_news_count > 0 %}
  // Region stuff here 
{% endif %}
```

https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/get-views-row-count-twig-drupal-8

Answer (score 0):

You could do it purely with CSS, just make it so the region itself only gets its width/height from the views rows.

You could also set the region to "display:none;" then use Javascript to detect if there's any views rows and change the display if it finds one.

I'm not sure if there's a simple solution in PHP. You could recreate the views db query in your theme's preprocessing, and use that to hide the region if it doesn't find any results.